# Manage Products page is not working

Tags: security, magento

I've installed SUPEE 6788 and from default, admin routing compatibility is "Enabled", all extensions work fine. However, when I "Disable" it, My Manage Products page is not working.

Does anyone know where this may be due to? Meaby I need also the update Magento to 1.9.2.2.?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log out and login again and check if it works..

if not then check the status of SUPEE6788 in Magento Connect Manager.

Comment: Hello Pt. It is also not working when I log out and login I have also delete the cache.

Comment: check status in magento connect manager and share screenshot of the connect manager.

Answer (score 0):

One of your extensions is probably not compatible with the new patch. This is a comprehensive description of what the patch does and included is a link to extensions that are and aren't compatible with the patch. Hopefully there'll be an upgrade that will resolve your issue.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87214/how-to-check-which-modules-are-affected-by-security-patch-supee-6788